# NullPointerException when trying to access views in a Kotlin fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

How to use Kotlin Android Extensions with `Fragment`s?
If I use them inside `onCreateView()`, I get this `NullPointerException` exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a
>   null object reference

Here is the fragment code:

```
package com.obaied.testrun.Fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.obaied.acaan.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_card_selector.*

public class CardSelectorFragment : Fragment() {
    val TAG = javaClass.canonicalName

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): CardSelectorFragment {
            return CardSelectorFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var rootView = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_selector, container, false)
        btn_K.setOnClickListener { Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated(): hello world"); }

        return rootView
    }
}
`
```

Comment: If you want to do it in onCreateView, btn_K will be a property on rootView as well.

You could do `rootView.btn_K.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Clean, rebuild and restart Android studio worked for me

Comment: @Otziii This thread was first written in 2015. The first answer has 259 votes and was accepted. I don't think its necessary to add more answers.

Comment: @Solidak I had this problem recently, tried all the answers and the only thing that made it work was what I now commented. I had an answer on this thread, but it just got downvoted, so I changed it to a comment. Seems like people are still having this issue, and no one mentioned to clean and restart.

Answer (score 489, accepted):

Kotlin synthetic properties are not magic and work in a very simple way. When you access `btn_K`, it calls for `getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_K)`.

The problem is that you are accessing it too soon. `getView()` returns `null` in `onCreateView`. Try doing it in the `onViewCreated` method:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    btn_K.setOnClickListener { Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated(): hello world"); }
}
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks.


Just a quick heads-up for future reference. I had another exception, and I dug a little deeper and it turns out that the Null Reference Exception was coming from an async callback to the UI thread where it would try to access the synthetic property, but it was already null at the time. Make sure to use the _Safe Call_ operator (?.) or some other null safety operator.


It would also help to keep a class reference of the view and not rely on synthetic properties outside of `onViewCreated()`

Comment: One question though - it generates different code for Activity and Fragment? If we use another structure that doesn't contain `getView()` or it cannot invoke `findViewById()`, is there a way to work around it? For example, teach it which function will return my layout?

Comment: You can also access it like `rootView.btn_K` if you have a view (and not just in fragments , this can be done everywhere)

Comment: It works ! However It should be more underlined from Kotlin documentation. I didn't notice this method until this post.. Thanks anyway !

Comment: it works. also kotterknife works this way not in Java where you can access it @ onCreateView of fragment. Good find though. Thanks

Comment: You're my superman! I'm was just trying to build a simple app with some trial and error and missed this simple answer while I was banging my head trying to understand why all elements were null

Comment: I always used it in onViewCreated, but still on some device (I got the report from Crashlytics) it got "must not be null" exception. The view is there. I inflate correct layout, it works on my device. It just strange not working on random device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise and informative answer!

Comment: @ArieAgung i have same problems that got worse lately. How to fix this case?

Answer (score 11):

You are calling this `btn_K` too soon as at that time it returns a null and is giving you Null Pointer Exception.

You can use these views by this synthetic plugin in `onActivityCreated()` method which is called just after `onCreateView()` of Fragment lifecycle.

```
onActivityCreated()
{
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        btn_K.setOnClickListener{}
}
```

Comment: I just want to point out that for some reasons, this answer worked for me while the accepted answer did not. My views are null in `onViewCreated` but then defined in `onActivityCreated`. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 8):

Synthetic properties generated by [Kotlin Android Extensions plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) needs a `view` for `Fragment/Activity` to be set before hand.

In your case, for `Fragment`, you need to use `view.btn_K` in `onViewCreated`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_selector, container, false)
    view.btn_K.setOnClickListener{} // access with `view`
    return view
}
```

Or better, you should only access synthetic properties in `onViewCreated`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_selector, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    btn_K.setOnClickListener{} // access without `view`
}
```

Please notice that `savedInstanceState` parameter should be nullable `Bundle?`, and also check [Importing synthetic properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

> It is convenient to import all widget properties for a specific layout
>   in one go:
>
> `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*`
>
> Thus if the layout filename is activity_main.xml, we'd import
>   `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*.`
>
> If we want to call the synthetic properties on View, we should also
>   import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*.`

Answer (score 5):

the only thing you need to do is:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var rootView = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_selector, container, false)
    rootView.btn_K.setOnClickListener { Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated(): hello world"); }

    return rootView
}
```

Comment: Yes, just use `val view = inflater.inflate() view.button.text = "caption"`.

Comment: This is the best answer - neatest solution for sure!

Comment: @CacheMeOutside no, because it's still boilerplate code `rootView.subView.doSomething`. It's better to use views starting from `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 1):

In Fragments please write your code in onActivityCreated:-

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_activity, container, false)

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        initialization()
        onClickLogin()
        onClickForgot()
        onClickSocailLogIn()

  }
```

Comment: Why? Where do have this knowledge? Why not `onViewCreated` instead?

Answer (score 0):

In my case nothing worked until I followed the advice from [Otziii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3301138/otziii) in the comments. Clean, rebuild (no restart needed), re-run the app. I also didn't need to go with `onActivityCreated` and just `onCreateView` did the trick.

One time I also made the error of inflating wrong layout, thus not getting the expected controls obviously.

Comment: i have seen it happening in `onActivityCreated` too

Answer (score 0):

no need to define companion object just call every id by a view like

```
 lateinit var mView: View
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list,container,false)

    mView.addProduct.setOnClickListener {

        val intent=Intent(activity,ProductAddActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }     return mView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to @Egor Neliuba's answer, Yes whenever you call a view without reference, kotlinex looks for a rootView, and since you are inside a fragment and fragment doesn't have `getView()` method. Therefore it might throw `NullPointerException`

There are two ways to overcome this,

- Either you override `onViewCreated()` as mentioned
- Or If you want to bind views in some other class(say anonymous), you can simply create an extension function like this,

  `fun View.bindViews(){...}`

The second approach is helpful, when you have a single fragment with multiple behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

```
class CardSelectorFragment : Fragment() {


val TAG = javaClass.canonicalName

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): CardSelectorFragment {
        return CardSelectorFragment()
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var rootView = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_selector, container, false)

    rootView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mTextView)?.setOnClickListener{
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated(): hello world");
    }
    //btn_K.setOnClickListener { Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated(): hello world"); }
    return rootView
}
```

}

**Here you are using btn_K.setOnClickListener before finding 
-You have to find the element form xml to your java/kotlin code by using findViewById then and then only you can perform operation on that view or element.

### -So that's why null pointer execption you got

**