# UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property pref has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I know a similar question has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176083/lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized). But that was due to butter knife library problem but my case is different. In my case when I use dagger injected properties in my base activity it shows me error **Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property pref has not been initialized**

But the same property when I use in my sub activity (Login activity) it works fine.

eg. **pref.setLanguage("abc") -> it works fine in login activity but throws error in base activity**

Here is my code:

**BaseActivity**

```kotlin
    abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var pref: AppSharedPreferences
    @Inject
    lateinit var utils: Utils
    lateinit var mCurrentLanguage: String
    protected lateinit var progressBarUtils: ProgressBarUtils

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        progressBarUtils = ProgressBarUtils(this)
        mCurrentLanguage = "EN"
        pref.setSelectedLanguage(mCurrentLanguage)   
    }
    }
```

**LoginActivity**

```kotlin
    class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private val TAG = this.javaClass.name
    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: LoginViewModelFactory


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(
                LoginViewModel::class.java)
        loadData("abc", "xyz")
        observerOnLoginResult()
        observerOnLoginError()
    }


    private fun observerOnLoginError() {
        loginViewModel.loginError().observe(this, Observer<String> {
            progressBarUtils.cancelProgressDialog()
            if (it != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, resources.getString(R.string.error_message) + it,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun observerOnLoginResult() {
        loginViewModel.loginResult().observe(this,
                Observer<LoginModel> {
                    progressBarUtils.cancelProgressDialog()
                    if (it != null) {
                        setData(it)
                    }
                })
    }

    private fun setData(loginData: LoginModel) {
        pref.setCurrentUserName(loginData.data.userName)
    }

    private fun loadData(email: String, password: String) {
        progressBarUtils.showProgressDialog()
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        var auth = Base64.encodeToString(("$email:$password").toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
        builder.append("Basic ")
        builder.append(auth)
        loginViewModel.getLoginData(builder.toString())
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        loginViewModel.disposeElements()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

**AppModule**

```kotlin
    @Module class AppModule(val app: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application = app


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreferences(): AppSharedPreferences = AppSharedPreferences(app)


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUtils(): Utils = Utils(app)
    }
```

**Builder Module**

```kotlin
    @Module abstract class BuildersModule {

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(LoginModule::class))
    abstract fun contributeLoginActivity(): LoginActivity

    @PerActivity
    abstract fun contributeBaseActivityActivity(): BaseActivity
    }
```

**AppComponent**

```kotlin
    @Singleton @Component(
        modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, BuildersModule::class))

    interface AppComponent { 
      fun inject(app: LotusApp)            
    }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't use an object before you initialize it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) // prefs called in parents onCreate!
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
  AndroidInjection.inject(this) // injection happens here
```

Get your calls in order. Easiest way to fix would be to move `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` before the call to `super.onCreate(...)`.

Comment: I forgot to add   **AndroidInjection.inject(this)** . Thank you @David.