# Kotlin Android Shared Preferences - lateinit property prefs has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/making-sharedpreferences-easy-with-kotlin), but an error occured when I try to assign a value to my Sh.Preference (`prefs.token = "sometoken"`):

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property prefs has not been initialized
```

I don't understand where's the bug, I also checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578618/kotlin-uninitializedpropertyaccessexception-lateinit-property-pref-has-not-been?s=1%7C340.9579).
Here are my code snippets

**Prefs.kt :**

```
class Prefs(context: Context) {
    private val PREFS_FILENAME = "com.example.myapp.prefs"
    private val PREFS_TOKEN = "token"
    private val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)

    var token: String?
        get() = prefs.getString(PREFS_TOKEN, "")
        set(value) = prefs.edit().putString(PREFS_TOKEN, value).apply()
}
```

**App.kt :**

```
val prefs: Prefs by lazy {
    App.prefs
}

class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var prefs: Prefs
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        prefs = Prefs(applicationContext)
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

`prefs.token` has a default value of `""`, so why the logs said that has not been initialized?

Comment: I wouldn't hold the shared preferences in a static way as it references context.

Comment: Try putting a print() statement in onCreate() to verify that it really gets called before you access the global prefs variable.

Comment: Where did you do this `prefs.token = "sometoken"`?

Comment: Your code is confusing. You have two different properties named prefs. Once is a by lazy val, and the other is a lateinit var. Also, it's not token that is the issue, but prefs.

Comment: Did you try removing lateinit var prefs: Prefs from the companion object block, place it outside... that might help

Comment: @lathspell I put a print, but I don't see it in the console logs... So that method isn't called.

Comment: @HongDuan I am using inside my MainActivity just to see if i can access and modify it

Comment: Check your Scope name.  @injecting thing should be in the same scope with current Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, problem found... The code was alright, I just missed to add this line

```
android:name=".App"
```

in the tag
 `<application` in my Android Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just initialize SharedPreference in  `onCreate()`, and all works

For example: **MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AppPreferences.init(this) // added this
}
```

**SharedPreferences object:**

```
    object AppPreferences {
        private const val NAME = "SpinKotlin"
        private const val MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        private lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
    
        // list of app specific preferences
        private val IS_FIRST_RUN_PREF = Pair("is_first_run", false)
    
        fun init(context: Context) {
            preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE)
        }
    
        /**
         * SharedPreferences extension function, so we won't need to call edit() and apply()
         * ourselves on every SharedPreferences operation.
         */
        private inline fun SharedPreferences.edit(operation: (SharedPreferences.Editor) -> Unit) {
            val editor = edit()
            operation(editor)
            editor.apply()
        }

        // getter and setter with Shared Preference     
        var temperature: Float
            // custom getter to get a preference of a desired type, with a predefined default value
            get() = preferences.getFloat("temp",1f )
    
            // custom setter to save a preference back to preferences file
            set(value) = preferences.edit {
                it.putFloat("temp", value)
            }
    }
```