# FXGL: Deprecation warning leads to kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException?

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

I am trying to follow the following [tutorial](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL/wiki/Adding-Sprite-Animations-%28FXGL-11%29),
 I use `eclipse` as my `IDE` of choice and `maven` for the dependencies. Since I am unfamiliar with `Kotlin` and I am actually programming in `Java` I have no idea how to solve the issue. I had a look at the following posts:

[un-initialized property access exception late-init property pref has not been initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578618/uninitializedpropertyaccessexception-lateinit-property-pref-has-not-been-initia) 
[How to check if a late-init variable has been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized)

**Exception:**

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property engine
 has not been initialized   at
 com.almasb.fxgl.dsl.FXGL$Companion.getAssetLoader(FXGL.kt:106)     at
 com.almasb.fxgl.dsl.FXGL$Companion.image(FXGL.kt:199)  at
 com.almasb.fxgl.dsl.FXGL.image(FXGL.kt)    at
 AnimationComponent.<init>(AnimationComponent.java:18)  at
 SimpleGameApp.initSettings(SimpleGameApp.java:15)  at
 com.almasb.fxgl.app.GameApplication.takeUserSettings(GameApplication.java:118)
    at
 com.almasb.fxgl.app.GameApplication.launch(GameApplication.java:96)
    at
 com.almasb.fxgl.app.GameApplication.launch(GameApplication.java:58)
    at SimpleGameApp.main(SimpleGameApp.java:37)
```

I have no clue what could be wrong, **I tried** to add some dependencies for `Kotlin` in my pom file but this didn't help either. I think a source of my problem could be the deprecation warning in my IDE which you can see in the image.

**Deprecation Warning fxgl.component**
[image: Img]

Comment: Based on the stacktrace, `AnimationComponent.<init>`, which is `new AnimationComponent` gets called in `initSettings()`. In the tutorial, there is no code inside `initSettings()`. There is full source code at the end of the tutorial page, please can you make sure it's copied verbatim: https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL/wiki/Adding-Sprite-Animations-%28FXGL-11%29#full-source-code

Comment: @AlmasB oh, thanks. I oversaw this i have put my code into initSettings() instead of initGame(). Problem solved!