# lateinit property S has not been initialized

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I want **inject** a **singleton** in another class by **kotlin** in **spring boot**.

> S.kt

```
 @Singleton
 @Component
 class S(
    private val userService: UserService,
    val companyRepo: CompanyRepo
 )
```

> WorkingGroup.kt

```
    class WorkingGroup(
        override val name: String = "",
        override val desc: String = ""
    ) : Csv() {

        fun isCompatible(ct2: WorkingGroup): Boolean = this == ct2

        companion object : ICsvEnumCompanion<WorkingGroup> {

            @Inject
            private lateinit var s: S

           override val VALUES: List<WorkingGroup>
            by lazy {
                val details = s.user().company.details ?: CompanyDetails()
                details.workingGroups.map { WorkingGroup(it.name, it.desc) }
            }
    }
}
```

By this code, I get below error:

```
Caused by: org.zalando.problem.DefaultProblem: Internal Server Error: lateinit property s has not been initialized
```

I search for this error and found some result like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176083/lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized), but the problem not solved.
How can I inject service in **companion object** in kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

In order for Spring to inject into a companion object you will need to create a setter for the field outside of the companion object. `WorkingGroup` will need to be a Spring managed bean in order for Spring to autowire it (inject dependencies).

```
@Component
class WorkingGroup(
    override val name: String = "",
    override val desc: String = ""
) : Csv() {

    fun isCompatible(ct2: WorkingGroup): Boolean = this == ct2

    companion object : ICsvEnumCompanion<WorkingGroup> {

        private lateinit var s: S

       override val VALUES: List<WorkingGroup>
        by lazy {
            val details = s.user().company.details ?: CompanyDetails()
            details.workingGroups.map { WorkingGroup(it.name, it.desc) }
        }
   }

   @Autowired
   fun setS(value: S) {
      s = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not solved. I get a hint from **@Autowired**:   _autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean_. @Dean

Comment: If you make the WorkingGroup a bean too, then it works.

Comment: @mgh if `WorkingGroup` is not a Spring managed bean, how do you create it in your code? Furthermore, how do you expect spring to autowire it?