# Android : Button on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

Hi I just started making Android apps with Kotlin a got small problem with my app

When I try to use OnclickListener my app crashes

[My code](https://pastebin.com/2NAW7ffh)

```
class fr_cooking : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        button.setOnClickListener({
            textView2.text = "blablabla"
        })

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_cooking, container, false)

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541650/kotlin-android-extensions-and-fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implememnt your onClick listener in following method :

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    }
```