# Views are null when layouts are inflated again

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a view with 4 containers (LinearLayouts). Each container will be filled with content depending on data. (Each content view is inflated with a layout and added to the container)

Previously I called `ButterKnife.bind(this, view)` after I inflated each of the layouts, when the data was loaded. Now I want to get rid of ButterKnife in favor of the kotlinx synthetic view binding.

My problem is, the first time the view is created and setup everything works fine. When I refresh the view, most of the views are null (which weren't null before and shouldn't be).

Some code:

```
private fun refresh() {
    //Get data...then...
    //Reset containers
    topup_container_one.removeAllViews()
    topup_container_two.removeAllViews()
    topup_container_three.removeAllViews()
    topup_container_four.removeAllViews()

    lateinit var contentOne: View
    lateinit var contentTwo: View
    lateinit var contentThree: View
    lateinit var contentFour: View
    val layoutInflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    if (someCondition) {
        contentOne = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, topup_container_one, false)
        contentTwo = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, topup_container_two, false)
        contentThree = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, topup_container_three, false)
        contentFour = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout4, topup_container_four, false)       
    } else { 
         // some other sort order, same principle
    }

    topup_container_one.addView(contentOne)
    topup_container_two.addView(contentTwo)
    topup_container_three.addView(contentThree)
    topup_container_four.addView(contentFour)
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topup_container_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

   //same for two, three, four

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anything I can do about that view mess? Maybe 'recall' the view binding?

Comment: do you call refresh after onViewCreated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541650/kotlin-android-extensions-and-fragments

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it would fail always I guess. refresh() just removes all views from the container and re inflates them.

Comment: `most of the views are null`- what are those views?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. All of the views were null. Just the "default" views were visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I bind my views again manually after inflating each container, it works.

So, what I do:

```
private var buttonVoucherVoiceInput: AppCompatImageButton? = null
private var editTextVoucher: EditText? = null
private var textInputLayoutVoucher: TextInputLayout? = null
private var buttonVoucherSubmit: Button? = null
//And many many more

private fun refresh() {

    ///...
    topup_container_one.addView(contentOne)
    topup_container_two.addView(contentTwo)
    topup_container_three.addView(contentThree)
    topup_container_four.addView(contentFour)

    //Find views again
    editTextVoucher = view!!.findViewById(R.id.topup_edittext_voucher)
    buttonVoucherSubmit = view!!.findViewById(R.id.topup_button_voucher_submit)
    textInputLayoutVoucher = view!!.findViewById(R.id.topup_til_voucher)
    buttonVoucherVoiceInput = view!!.findViewById(R.id.topup_button_voucher_voice)

}
```

Annoying, but it works again.. And I can remove Butterknife from my project. (No disrespect, I loved it) :)

Comment: Is this seriously the only solution to this? So kotlin synthetic view binding is practically pointless because you have to dynamically assign them anyways if you have orientation changes?

Comment: I don't think thats the case for more simple setups and especially for orientation changes. 
But for me it was the case, because, depending on the data from the backend, other views and containers have been inserted / inflated into the layout. In addition, the view containers were also replaced by others etc.. It was a strange setup to be honest. Back then this was the way it worked for this setup.