# Why does btnOpen return null when I invoke it on onCreateView with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I get the error information

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

when I run the code `btnOpen.setOnClickListener`.

But the system is OK when I run the code

```
var s= rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOpen)
```

why?

**Code**

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_tab_clipboard.*

import info.dodata.clipboard.R
import utility.openActivity

class UITabClipboard: Fragment(){
    private lateinit var  mContext: Context

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tab_clipboard, container, false)
        mContext = rootView.context

        var s= rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOpen) //It's OK
        s.setOnClickListener(){
            mContext.openActivity<UIAbout>()
        }     


        btnOpen.setOnClickListener {           //It cause error
            mContext.openActivity<UIAbout>()
        }

        return rootView
    }


}
```

Comment: Use it inside  `onActivityCreated` method and check

Comment: shouldn't you be using `val` instead of `var`

Comment: `onCreateView()` is too early. You can only use synthetic view refs after `onCreateView()` in the fragment lifecycle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541650/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-access-views-in-a-kotlin-fragment

Comment: `btnOpen` is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks! But why is `var s= rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOpen)` OK ?

Comment: @HelloCW because it's not accessed as a synthetic view.