# Text in button is not displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

This is the class

```
data class Crime(
val id:UUID=UUID.randomUUID(),
var title:String="",
var date: Date= Date(),
var isSolved:Boolean=false)
```

I want to display current date as a text in button.(Below is the layout for button)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"/>
```

This is the .kt code to set the text in button

```
crime_date?.apply {
            text = crime.date.toString()
            isEnabled = false
        }
```

Comment: Where is `crime` initialized

Comment: Try the updated answer @Pawan Acharya

Comment: Is there anything being displayed other than the intended dateTime text? Or the button is just empty without any text?

Comment: @Gulshan  tools:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018" this code doesnt shows any text on button but android:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018" shows the hardcoded string which is not intended.
I want the string from date() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools is just for development, text is the property that you want to set, to see when the app is built.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"/>
```

should be

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/crime_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"/>
```

Check if you have a property text declared your app, before setting in apply, like

```
var text = ""
crime_date?.apply {
            text = crime.date.toString()
            isEnabled = false
        }
```

try if

```
crime_date?.text = "data"
```

is working, if it is working the problem is with the crime.date.toString() part, try to debug with breakpoints, to check the values.

Edit:

If the code is called from a fragment make sure that it is called in or after onViewCreated, like:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        crime_date?.apply {
            text = crime.date.toString()
            isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: crime_date.text = "Hello world" writing this code
it throws error
"crime_date must not be null"

Comment: Then the issue is that the corresponding xml does not contains the button with id crime_date. It is in a fragment or an activity? If it is a fragment, then you should call the mentioned code after, or in onViewCreated() method

Comment: Where did you put this code? It should be in override fun onViewCreated(...

Comment: Yes it is in onCreateView() method
' 
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        crime_date?.apply {
            text = crime.date.toString()
            isEnabled = false
        }'

Comment: Not onCreateView, onViewCreated, see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you that worked.
Can you explain the reason or the good source where i can learn about it.

Comment: Read the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541650/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-access-views-in-a-kotlin-fragment&ved=2ahUKEwjJ_c-oo_HkAhXHxaYKHSA2DoIQjjgwAHoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2aeuVrjMdluswIrOFVJpNo,. Also mark my answer as correct and maybe upvote if it helped.

Comment: Why i am not able to implement onClickListner in that method(onViewCreated)?

   crime_date.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

Comment: That's a separate question, open a new one I you do not find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")   
val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
crime_date.text = currentDate
System.out.println("Current DATE is  "+currentDate)
```

Comment: tried your code but it didnt worked.
Date() should have worked for this. I tried date() method in simple kotlin program it worked there but it is not showing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
crime_date?.apply {
        val crime = Crime()
        text = crime.date.toString()
        isEnabled = false
    }
```

In your `Button` remove

```
tools:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"
```

with

```
android:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"
```

Comment: I have already made object for the class Crime globally. So adding that line didnt helped

Answer (score 0):

there is mistake in your xml correct this

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wed Nov 14 11:56 EST 2018"/>
```